# xamarin how to install the distribution app to the iphone

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ipa

I used to be able to install and test my ipa, which I had signed for the store (distribution), on my Iphone.

Now after some update (Xamarin/Visual Studio 2017) it is not possible anymore.

When I will install this ipa from xcode => Devices & Simulators etc. I get the error : A valid provisioning profile for htis executable was not found.

But if I upload the ipa with the application loader to the store, everthing is fine.

Is it not possible to install the ipa (distributed) to my iphone?

regards
Dario

Comment: Well do you have the provisioning profiles of your app? The one you getting from apple developer console? Because it seems they are not available in your mac keystore

Comment: Yes I have provisioning profiles. 1 for development and 1 for distribution. In the develpment profile there is my Iphone registered. In the keychain access i have only my certificates

Comment: In your entitlement.plist did you change the app to a devlopment app? And do you have the right provisioning profile selected ? I mean the development one?

Comment: When I select the development profile, i can install it on my device. But when i select the distributed one, I can't install the app on my device. In the past I could install the app with distributed signing... And I would love to install the distributed signing app on my iphone before I upload it to the store. Because so I can test again.

Comment: Why don't you use TestFlight?

Comment: In my experience, apps signed with a distribution profile can only be installed from the app store. To install apps with an ad-hoc distribution profile, you needed an Apple Developer Enterprise program membership. And I believe the profiles for ad-hoc and app store were different. Testing with the developer profile should be identical to testing with the distribution profile anyway. The signature should not affect app behavior, only install.

Comment: Make sure the bundle id in the info.plist file matches the distribution bundle id